# JSON parse Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I have a JSON data and there are some restrictions in JSON data to pass data in the same format (like string, JSON etc). below is my code:-

```
     buttons:[{
            type: "postback",
            title: p.name,
            payload: "get_product" 
     }]
```

here the payload key should be pass in the string but I have to pass some other keys also like product_id, name etc. so what I did is:-

```
     buttons:[{
            type: "postback",
            title: p.name,
            payload: "{'payload': 'get_product, 'product_id': #{p.id} }"
     }]
```

now when I will get the payload data then it is like this `payload = "{'payload': 'get_product', 'product_id': d644bfda-2194-447c-b0f1-5d4f52c783a4 }"` and when I parse the string to JSON and it throws error `JSON.parse(payload)` `Processing by Messenger::Bot::Space::StationController#receive as */*
*** JSON::ParserError Exception: 784: unexpected token at '{'payload': 'get_product', 'product_id': d644bfda-2194-447c-b0f1-5d4f52c783a4 }'`.

I know the reason why its throws error because the payload data inside the single quotes so when I did it to `payload = '{"payload": "get_product", "product_id": "d644bfda-2194-447c-b0f1-5d4f52c783a4" }'` and when I did run `JSON.parse(payload)`

> (byebug)
>
> payload = '{"payload": "get_product", "product_id":
>   "d644bfda-2194-447c-b0f1-5d4f52c783a4" }'
>
> (byebug)
>   JSON.parse(payload)
>
> {"payload"=>"get_product",
>   "product_id"=>"d644bfda-2194-447c-b0f1-5d4f52c783a4"}

But the issue is when I am using single quotes outside of the `'{"payload": "get_product", "product_id" => #{p.id} }'` then product_id key value not printed because of string interpolation so what should I do.

Comment: have you tried `payload: "{'payload': 'get_product, 'product_id': '#{p.id}' }"` ?

Comment: Anyway, you're missing a single quote in `payload: "{'payload': 'get_product, 'product_id': #{p.id} }"` after get_product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
"{'payload': 'get_product, 'product_id': #{p.id} }"
```

Do this:

```
{payload: 'get_product', product_id: p.id }.to_json
```

This will return something like:

```
"{\"payload\":\"get_product\",\"product_id\":123}"
```

...So as you can see, all the [hard work like correctly escaping quotation marks](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding/JSONGemEncoder/EscapedString/to_json) is taken care of for you.